# Cleared cache and Chrome won't stop using old CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, caching, browser

I've been developing a website locally and have uploaded the website a couple of times to my server on Siteground for testing. With this newest upload I *cannot* for the life of me get chrome to stop using my old css file.

I have completely cleared the cache many, many times. I have removed the CSS files from my server *completely* and done the same, so the site should be rendering free of any and all CSS. I have double-checked via cPanel file management to make sure there are no CSS files.

It renders as it should (with no CSS) in every other browser but still not in Chrome! I imagine this is a very simple problem with a simple answer and I am just not seeing it.

Here's [the website](http://www.woodworkandwhatnot.dylanstarkdevelopment.com/).

What it looks like in Chrome:

[image: Page in Chrome]

What it looks like in every other browser:

[image]

Comment: Did you try CTRL + SHIFT + R?

Comment: @Mike no I had not and that worked! Any idea why that works but using devtools "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" or any other method does not?

Comment: I'm not sure where the option is, but CTRL + SHIFT + R is a shorthand for Hard Reload. If you open DevTools and then click RMB on the reload button you will see that Hard Reload option.

Comment: @Mike hmmm that's odd, I had already Hard Reloaded the page the exact way you specified as well as "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" to no avail. I must've changed something along the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> instead (shortcut key for Hard Reload in Chrome).

You can also try add ?ver=anynumber at the end of your linked css to force browsers to reload it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css?ver=100">
```

Comment: This was the first approach, that helped for me!

Comment: This will not only force the browser to cache miss but cdn as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows then try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> keys.

On Mac OS X try holding both the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> keys and press the <kbd>R</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

When you click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> in Chrome it opens the "Clear browsing data" -page. You can and should check the check-box "Browsing history".

However note that above that you have the setting for "Time Range". Choose "All time". That seems to NOT be the default.

If you don't choose "All time" then perhaps counter-intuitively older resources stay in the cache whereas only ones cached during last hour or so may be removed.